# Accessing elements inside map<int,string[4]>

Tags: c++, gcc, stl, dictionary, std

How would I access elements from the following map:

```
map<int, string[4]> * my_map;
```

I used to do it through the at() operator

```
string * val_ptr = my_map->at(key);
```

Recently, I have discovered that this is a non standard feature of my compiler and the correct way of doing it is through `operator[]`. Unfortunately, the compiler keeps trying to convert my key to `string [4]`:

```
string * val_ptr = my_map->operator[](key);

error: conversion from ‘int’ to non-scalar type ‘std::string [4]’ requested
```

I have looked online, but there don't seem to be any examples with a map of string arrays. Am I doing something invalid? Should I be using a vector instead, and if so, would it be slower to create and access?

Comment: Since when is `map<int, string[4]>` even legal? `string[4]` or any other array is not assignable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use of `.at()` function is **not** non-Standard anymore. It is in the Standard C+11 (see [doc](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/at)).

Now, this,

```
string * val_ptr = my_map->operator[](key);
```

which is correct, but it should be written as:

```
string * val_ptr = (*my_map)[key];
```

as it is more succinct.

As for the compiler error, it is somewhere else.

---

In fact, I believe, the problem is coming from somewhere, and caused by pointer declaration of the map. Why don't you declare the map as:

```
map<int, string[4]> my_map; //no pointer
```

and then use

```
string * val_ptr = my_map[key];
```

---

Even better if you use `std::vector`:

```
std::map<int, std::vector<std::string> > my_map; //no pointer
```

and then use

```
std::vector<std::string> & val = my_map[key];
```

Comment: What I meant by non-standard is that it is not listed here http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/map/, and the few online posts I came across discussing it mentioned that this function was available only is some versions of the gcc compiler.

Comment: @Pavel: I should have mentioned that it is Standard in C++11. : http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/at

Answer (score 2):

You could use  `std::map<int, std::array<std::string,4> >` (or have your own `class fourstring_t` containing the four strings)  and use `std::map<int,fourstring_t>` and you can also use

```
 string second = (my_map->at(key))[1];
```

to retrieve the second string (of rank 1) in your array of strings.

And the at method is standard, as Nawaz reminded it.

As UncleBens reminded, you need the `fourstring_t` type to be assignable.